# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS crashes after login

Tags: login

Decided to upgrade to the new LTS today, so I backed up my data and created a live usb with unetbootin and wiped my drive clean.  Install was a little clunky but everything seemed to go just fine.  Issue is whenever I log in, the desktop loads but either it totally freezes (mouse not moving, keyboard not functioning), or the mouse will still be moveable but nothing lights up when hovered over and clicks do nothing same with keyboard.  This happens every time I log in.

I rebooted and used the check disc tool and it reports everything is fine.  Tried reinstalling, same issue.  Made a second disk with Ubuntu's Startup Disk Creator program, install went smoother that time but same issue on login.

I am using a HP DV6000 laptop that worked just fine with 12.04

I am at a loss here, maybe somebody has a little insight, any help would be appreciated, much love for this community

Comment: I've been having the same/similar issue. I have a computer that I put together (old desktop comp) and the machine "freezes" after logging in. I tried re-installing it and nothing... I did manage to go to tty1 and tty2 then going back to the desktop screen and I saw a screen reporting that there was an issue and if I wanted it to "report problem", I however, have not been able to setup the wifi since the desktop seems to freeze. Sometimes the mouse moves but it takes a good 30 seconds of delay. My hard drive also seems to be working hard for some reason. Ubuntu 12.04 was working fine...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is how I fixed my issue:

When the computer loaded and I saw the ubuntu splash screen, I held the shift key until I see the kernel loader. I chose the advanced settings and loaded the kernel in recovery mode. I added the WiFi and went to the ubuntu menu [super button] and typed "Additional Drivers". Then I change my video driver from X.Org X server to NVIDIA. I have a GeForce 6150SE Video Card.

Hope this helps someone in the interwebs!

Cheers!

Comment: Did you use version 173 or 304? I remember having to do something similar with 12.04 now, using unity 2D to prevent desktop from crashing until I got the drivers working. Trying version 304 right now

Comment: I am using `NVIDIA legacy binary driver - version 304.117 from nvidia-304-updates (proprietary)` I tried this one first and it worked.

Comment: Same problem have had it before after upgrading but now recovery mode wont work

Answer (score 15):

I had the same issue. I tried to reinstall `ubuntu-desktop`, `lightdm`, `compiz`, but nothing helped, only this:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

Comment: You are the man!

Comment: FYI you press CTRL-ALT-F2 to switch to a shell and do it from there.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is a video card problem, and here is how I solved it.

1. Reboot and hold the shift key on the keyboard.
2. Select boot in recovery mode...when that option screen appears.
3. After ubuntu loads up do a normal reboot(**do not hold shift key**) and this time log in with your password.
4. Click on system settings. (a new page will open)
5. Click on Software and updates. (a new page will open)
6. Select Additional drivers.(an automatic scan for drivers that are needed or missing will be done)
7. You will see that [X.Org.X Server] is being used....and that is not the correct driver..So select one of the Nvidia drivers instead...then click apply.
8. Reboot one more time and log in with your password and your problem should be no more.

Answer (score 2):

I will tell you how i solved the same problem.
After I installed 14.04 I had same issues: Desktop wouldn't load, or it would load but the mouse and menus were frozen.

1. I restarted computer, holding Shift, and loaded Advanced Settings -> Recovery Mode. Ubuntu loaded without the video drivers, which block the system.
2. I went to Additional Drivers, but the list was empty, applications couldn't be installed from the Software Center and I  couldn't install anything from Terminal. I logged out and logged back in. After this, Additional drivers were in the list and I could select the desired proprietory driver.
3. Restarted computer and everything worked fine.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem a bit differently. I uninstalled Compiz by running the following two lines in terminal.

```
sudo apt-get remove compiz-plugins
sudo apt-get remove compizconfig-settings-manager
```

It has not hang for the entire afternoon. Down side is I no longer have my wobbly windows.