# trouble starting up Trusty Tahr

Tags: 14.04

I have just installed the Ubuntu 14.04 LTS obtained from the link on the page "http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop"

After I login giving my password I expect to see the initial desktop, but instead the dialog box disappears from the screen and the system seems to be in some infinite loop.
I do not know how to proceed further.

Comment: Perhaps this could help http://itsfoss.com/fix-unity-freezes-after-login-ubuntu-14-04/

Comment: I tried to work as given at the link. The command 'sudo apt-get install -reinstall ubuntu-desktop' reports an error as follows   "E: Command line option 'r' [from -reinstall] is not known" I just removed the word reinstall and issued the command. After completing the procedure the status has not changed. Mosr help please.

Comment: Try to install "Additional Drivers": http://askubuntu.com/questions/449479/ubuntu-14-04-lts-crashes-after-login

Comment: Following seems to have worked for me.

Comment: Following seems to have worked for me. First I have followed the instructions given at the link "http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop" As stated in the earlier comment the "-reinstall" has given me problem. But rest of the commands were executed. This was then followed by the command "sudo apt-get install nvidia-current". This I found on the link "http://askubuntu.com/questions/449479/ubuntu-14-04-lts-crashes-after-login" that was provided to me on my previous comment.