# Windows not appearing in Grub, Ubuntu 17.10 freezing after login

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, nvidia, crash

Setup/Goal:

I have two SSDs, one which has Windows 10 on it and one which runs Ubuntu.  Previously, I set my boot order to go to my Windows SSD first, which would run Windows without a Grub screen.  When I needed to use Ubuntu, I would switch the boot order and a Grub screen would appear where I could choose either Ubuntu or Windows.  These are the settings I would like to return to.

Backstory:

I deleted my Ubuntu partitions with the intent to reinstall (I now understand that was my grave mistake).  I deleted Grub and the computer was left unable to boot.  I ran the [boot-repair tool](https://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/) and the result was that my Windows drive would boot to:

```
error: no such device: (series of letters and numbers).
error: unknown filesystem.
Entering rescue mode...
grub rescue>
```

and my Ubuntu drive would once again boot to Grub with both OS's.

I tried to run the boot repair again (likely another mistake) to fix my Windows drive, which leads me to my current problem.

Problem:

When I boot to either drive, I am presented with a Grub screen that does not contain an option to boot to Windows 10.  When I start up Ubuntu I can login, but the entire system freezes a second or two after loading the desktop.  I have researched a bit and found [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/449479/ubuntu-14-04-lts-crashes-after-login).  When I run

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

I am given a bunch of failed to fetch statements along with

```
Unable to fetch some archives, try running apt-get update or apt-get --fix-missing
```

Running

```
sudo apt-get update
```

returns a bunch of problem unlinking and failed to fetch statements.

```
sudo apt-get --fix-missing
```

returns a list of commands for apt-get.

My graphics card is a nVidia GTX 970, and I believe I need to update the drivers, then fix the boot issues.

Comment: When you say `run the boot repair again (likely another mistake) to fix my Windows drive`  do you mean the Ubuntu Boot Repair utility? I think you should remove the Ubuntu SSD drive, then use the Windows Installation DVD and choose Repair there. If that is successful, remove the Windows SSD, then either run Boot Repair or install a fresh copy of Ubuntu.

Comment: @WillemK boot repair is a 3rd-party tool (I have it linked in the second paragraph above).  I have Windows 8 discs but I upgraded to Windows 10 so I don't have discs on hand.  Is there any other option?

Comment: Yes, that is was I refer to as the Ubuntu Repair Tool. There probably is a tool to rebuild the MBR for Windows 10, but I don't know any name/website. I stopped at Windows 7.

Comment: @WillemK The repair tool actually has a repair MBR option!  I ran it, and I have Windows again (at least for now).  Thank you so much for the advice!  It's not an issue, but I noticed that Windows didn't appear on the Grub screen when booting from the Ubuntu drive.  Any reason for this?  Also, any advice regarding Ubuntu crashing?