# Ubuntu 18.04 freezes after login

Tags: drivers, 18.04, nvidia, login

I have a new built PC.

I7-8700.
Asus prime z390-a.
GeForce rtx 2080.
8gb ram.
2tb m2.
2tb hard drive (not currently connected during ubuntu install).

After a couple of attempts I managed to install ubuntu.

However after I restarted it now seems to freeze after login.

After researching it it appears this may be a problem with the nvidia drivers.

[Ubuntu 14.04 LTS crashes after login](https://askubuntu.com/questions/449479/ubuntu-14-04-lts-crashes-after-login)

The suggested solution is to install these drivers but how can i do this if I can't log in?